# ¿Cómo puedo subir archivos al servidor?

Tags: php, angularjs

Buenas tardes comunidad, de antemano muchas gracias

Tengo esta inquietud en cuanto a poder subir archivos al servidor, hasta ahi facilmente se puede gestionar, pero la duda surge es para subir los archivos ligados a un usarui determinado en mi BD, si por ejemplo Pepito Perez sube una foto, que simplemente se visualice en el perfil del usuario.

He buscado mucho en internet y creo que no he encontrado lo que he buscado porque todos los tutoriales que he visto han sido subiendo un archivo cualquiera pero sin el uso de las sesiones.

Gracias por la atencion prestada, y se que es algo que puede generar algun debate pero pueden instruirme o guiarme de la mejor manera.

Comment: Debes usar sesiones y en esta guardar el `id` del usuario y cuando subas el archivo en tu tabla o carpeta relacionas este `id` al archivo, esa es la forma más fácil de hacerlo. Un ejemplo cualquier red social que maneje imágenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te explico como lo hago yo:

1.El usuario (inicia sesión A este punto ya tienes que tener tu base de datos de usuarios, tu sistema de login y register)

2.Hay un formulario para subir una foto:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!---Tienes los campos que quieras aquí pero el más importante es es el input para recibir la imagen-->
    <input type="file" name="fotoUsuario">
</form>
```

3.Ahora cuando tu usuario envie el formulario tu lo vas a procesar con php, lo que yo hago es subir la imagen a un folder de mi sitio y guardar los siguientes campos en la base de datos:

Base de datos: `FotosUsuarios`:

```
-----------------------------------------
|idFoto    | NombreFoto    | idUsuario  |
-----------------------------------------
|1         | natacion.jpg  | 1          | <----Ejemplo
```

Así sería la esctructura aunque lo que yo hago es cambiar el nombre del archivo por caracteres al azar más para que sea dificil que los archivos se sobreescriben así si dos personas o más suben el archivo con el minmo nombre hay probabilidad menor de que se sobreescribar, quedando los nombres generados algo como estos ejemplos:

```
lLD3UI03JD0J393UH39FUH943HF934HF9.jpg 
LDOAHDASDU893H2U9DASDKJG283RR9H23.jpg
KJJH982HD9823JD3902J2309DJ902J230.jpg
```

Ahora al mostrar la imagen del usuario harías una consulta a la base de datos como esta:

```
"SELECT * FROM FotosUsuarios WHERE idUsuario = 1" //el idUsuario = 1 cambia ya en la base de datos por una consulta con una variable cambias el 1 por la variable con el id del usuario
```

Ahora tu resultado devuelve un arreglo con la información (Claro si esta existe) y lo guardas en una variable, por ejemplo `$resultado;`

Y a la hora de mostrarla:

```
echo "<img src='rutaDeDondeSubesLasImagenes/" . $resultado['NombreFoto'] ."'>";
```

De esa forma ya tendrías tu sistema de imágenes en una base de datos con cada imagen ligada a un usuario.

Si esto to fue de ayuda me agradaría que elijas mi respuesta ya que si me tomó algo de tiempo escribirla, si tienes alguna duda no dudes en decirme, saludos!

Comment: Excelente aporte, muchas gracias por la guia.